# When i click on the app url..it is taking me to the home page and not the app download page 

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent chapter;
    chapter = new Intent("c.theworld.com.nikhil.CHAPTER");
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.subjects:
        try {
            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=nik.trivia"));
            marketIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            startActivity(marketIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(chapter);
        }
        break;
    }
```

It worked on my phone.. but it is not taking me to the app's download page..it is taking me to the home page of google play ( market )..!
It is also opening the page without internet..i have added the internet permissions

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying this in emulator? If yes then be sure **you have installed Android Market application** in your emulator. Or just test it **on Android device** which has already installed Android Market application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your activity to Android Manifest file? Register all the activities which you are calling through intent.

Comment: As you are downloading the .apk file so you have to specify type for it as follows and also add .apk extension to ur URL. Intent 'intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"));
intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive";'